# Deadlock like behavior in Oracle 12c on select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have an oracle 12c R2 warehouse (an extensively elaborate db schema our app creates). I have run a TOOL(internal to our product) that runs multiple queries to fetch data and I see logs stuck at a point. Looks like there is some db query taking too long to finish. I need to find out what is going on.

I tried to check on the fly queries with following.

```
select x.sid
      ,x.serial#
      ,x.username
      ,x.sql_id
      ,x.sql_child_number
      ,optimizer_mode
      ,hash_value
      ,address
      ,sql_text
from   v$sqlarea sqlarea
      ,v$session x
where  x.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
and    x.sql_address    = sqlarea.address
and    x.username       is not null;
```

This gives me multiple rows for one query lets call it A(second row and so on in the snapshot below) and few more rows for another query B(3rd row and so on in the snapshot below). These 2 queries have joins on table T. Now, I don't know what that mean. I tried following query to find all db locks but it just return a very irrelevant result.

Following is the snapshot of db result from toad for above query.

[image: Toad result grid]

Please help me understand what such a result from the first query might imply. Execution of the TOOL takes about 6 hours and finishes successfully.

Comment: Readers (=select statement) will never block anything else.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name any input on what the db snap might imply ? both the queries run on same table and some additional table for each query and this common table has millions of rows. But the execution should not be taking so long to finish. We have indexes in place and this slowness is a recent event

Comment: `v$session` just shows you what's currently running. If you want to find out which of those are running slowly, try looking at `v$session_longops`, or take each query from the results and do some performance testing on it - timing, explain plan, etc. Also in TOAD, try the Session Browser. DB performance issues are a huge topic though.

Comment: If you add something like `v$session.last_call_et` to your query, that will show you how long a particular query has been running (which may or may not point at the problem if the thing that is slow is a loop where a query is being executed millions of times).  But it probably makes more sense to grab an AWR report (assuming you're licensed to do so) or a Statspack report of the period in question.  That will show you how much time each query has consumed in aggregate.